# How to arrange specifics elements within a grid?

Tags: html, css

I'm really new at this (i just have like a month studying HTML and CSS, and i just recently discovered this awesome Site) and I'm trying my best to learn to code, especially since I'm trying to make a living out of it.

Anyway. I wanna know how do I organize specifics elements within a grid?

I used CSS grid to create a basic Template, but I wanna know how do I move those elements within the grids.

Here's the codepen I created (link if does not work [link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Fry-Szopen/pen/VyWamp#code-area) :

```
<p data-height="449" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="VyWamp" data-default-tab="css,result" data-user="Fry-Szopen" data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="Learning CSS grid." data-preview="true" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/Fry-Szopen/pen/VyWamp/">Learning CSS grid.</a> by Erwin Velasquez Jimenez (<a href="https://codepen.io/Fry-Szopen">@Fry-Szopen</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
```

sorry if this question is dumb, but I'm really new and all this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "move the elements within the grids?" Are you looking to move the content within each of the CSS blocks? Move the blocks in general? Add the ability for users to drag and drop content into new places? Something else?

Comment: I mean to organize the child elements within a grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, @fry Szopen,
If you are organizing divs with the CSS Grid, elements of the those div (also child div) does not follow css grid, so you can treat them as any normal div.

you can use any display property in these child divs. like below pseudo code

```
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child1">
            <div class="grand-child"></div>
            <div class="grand-child"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="child2">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="child3">

      </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS can be --

```
.parent{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.child1{
      display: inline-block;
}
.child2{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

I have modified your snippet in [codepen](https://codepen.io/amitsoni7/pen/jYLNEK) have a look.

Comment: So that means I could use a grid, within a grid, or flex within a grid... Thats freaking awesome.